# SQL : Group by with multiple values and avoid null in that group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with values like this, here i need to have one row for each Trans Id. I can have min of Trans data for that record

```
    Trans Date  Trans id    Name
12/1/2017 14:44 T1  
12/1/2017 16:44 T1          test
12/1/2017 16:44 T2
```

Need output like this

```
Trans Date       Trans id   Name
12/1/2017 14:44     T1      test
12/1/2017 16:44     T2
```

i tried query like this, but it is giving me two rows of Name

```
select unique min(Trans Date), Trans id, Name from tabl1 group by Trans id, Name
```

but getting all the results. Please suggest

Comment: i dont know , why question is down voted. This is real time scenario for us. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it with `row_number` and `max` analytical functions.

Also using column names, with spaces, should be enclosed in `Double Quotes` but it would make it `case sensitive`. Check your table definition for correct column names.

```
select "Trans id" ,"Trans Date",m_name as name
from 
(
select t.*, 
 row_number() over (partition by "Trans id" order by "Trans Date") as rn
 ,max(name) over (partition by "Trans id" order by "Trans Date") as m_name
from table1 t
)
where rn=1
```

Comment: This is not returning required values. Getting all null rows of name.

Comment: what if you have name for all 3 rows, like 'test1,test,test2`. And what if all `name` are null. What is the expected output on that case.

Comment: if  name comes it is  coming for only one row of trans id of multiple trans dates otherwise it would be null for the trans ids of trans dates. Need to display, only one row for trans id

Comment: If there is only 1 not null `name` per `trans id`, then check the updated answer.

Comment: this helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Often, the most efficient method in Oracle is to use `keep`:

```
select trans_id, min(trans_date),
       min(name) keep (dense_rank first order by trans_date desc) as name
from tab1
group by trans_id;
```